# Understanding some nth-child examples

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am learning CSS and i was doing some experiments with nth-child. Lets say i have the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div p:nth-child(n+3) 
      {
        color: red;
      } 
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p> 1</p>
      <p> 2</p>
      <p> 3</p>
      <p> 4</p>
      <p> 5</p>
      <p> 6</p>
      <p> 7</p>
      <p> 8</p>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

1. Why does it start coloring the elements starting from `<p>2</p>` when i specified that i want it to count only `<p>` elements (can you even do that)?
2. Lets say that i have another  element same as the other one with 8 `<p>` elements in it, How can i specify that i want only the 5th `<p>` element of the 2nd `<div>` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `<h1>` shares the same `<div>` parent as the `<p>` elements (in other words, the `<h1>` and `<p>` elements are siblings of one another). That makes the `<h1>` the first child, and thus the first `<p>` becomes the second child, the second `<p>` becomes the third child (at which point `:nth-child(n+3)` starts matching elements), and so on.

   For elements that differ by tag name, you can use `:nth-of-type()` instead:

   ```
   div p:nth-of-type(n+3) 
   {
     color: red;
   }
   ```
2. Like so:

   ```
   div:nth-child(2) p:nth-of-type(5) 
   {
     color: red;
   }
   ```

   Again, if there are any other siblings among the `<div>` elements, `:nth-child()` will not work as you expect. You can always replace it with another `:nth-of-type()` like so:

   ```
   div:nth-of-type(2) p:nth-of-type(5) 
   {
     color: red;
   }
   ```